# Binary search infinite recursion

Tags: matlab, search, binary-search

I have written simple code in Matlab for binary Search. It's working properly if the searched item is in the array but goes into an infinite recursion loop if not.

I'm not sure where the problem lies.

```
function [] = BinarySearch(A,beg,last,item)
mid=floor((last+beg)/2);
if (beg)<=last
    if item==A(mid)
        fprintf('Item found at position %d \n',mid);
    else    
        if(item<A(mid))
            BinarySearch(A,beg,mid,item)
        else
            BinarySearch(A,mid,last,item)
        end    
    end
else
     fprintf('Item not found\n');
end
```

Comment: To debug the function, you could print out the values of `mid` and `beg` in the function and see what the outputs are when an infinite loop is encountered.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Imagine the really simple case that you only have 2 items in your list

```
A = [1 3]
```

and you call your `BinarySearch` on an `item` which would lie in the middle of the list. Look at the comments below, which follow how your function behaves...

```
BinarySearch(A, 1, 2, 2)
% mid = 1
% item ~= A(1): go to else
% item >  A(1): go to else
% BinarySearch(A, 1, 2, 2)
% ... rinse and repeat
```

If your `item` was too small

```
BinarySearch(A, 1, 2, 0)
% mid = 1
% item ~= A(1): go to else
% item <  A(1)
% BinarySearch(A, 1, 1, 0)
%  mid = 1
%  beg <= last (this is still true)
%  item ~= A(1): go to else
%  item <  A(1)
%  BinarySearch(A, 1, 1, 0)
%  ... rinse and repeat
```

Similarly for an `item` which is larger than any in the list,

```
BinarySearch(A, 1, 2, 5)
% leads to BinarySearch(A, 1, 2, 5)
% ... repeat!!
```

**You keep re-checking the same region, because your left (`beg`) and right (`last`) indices are allowed to both stay the same.**

---

Let's re-implement the function, returning an actual value instead of just printing out the position to the console too. The comments directly relate to the numbered steps in the [Wikipedia article for binary search](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_search_algorithm#Procedure), which looks similar in structure to what you've attempted:

```
function idx = BinarySearch(A, L, R, item)
%% BINARYSEARCH search for an item in the array A. Assumes that A is sorted ascending
% 1. Should be initially called using idx = BinarySearch(A, 1, n, item)
% where n is the number of elements in A, numel(A)
    % 2. if L > R, the search terminates as unsuccessful
    if L > R
        idx = 0;
    else
        % 3. set m (position of middle element) to the floor of (L+R)/2
        m = floor((L+R)/2);
        % 4. if Am < item, set L to m+1 and go to 2.
        if A(m) < item
            L = m + 1; % YOU MISSED THIS STEP, CAUSING OVERLAPPING SEARCH REGIONS
            idx = BinarySearch(A, L, R, item);
        % 5. if Am > item, set R to m-1 and go to 2.
        elseif A(m) > item
            R = m - 1; % THE OTHER HALF OF THE STEP YOU MISSED
            idx = BinarySearch(A, L, R, item);
        % 6. Now Am = item, search is done, return index
        else 
            idx = m;
        end
    end
end
```

Tests with `A` as before:

```
BinarySearch(A, 1, 2, 2); % returns 0: not found
BinarySearch(A, 1, 2, 0); % returns 0: not found
BinarySearch(A, 1, 2, 5); % returns 0: not found
BinarySearch(A, 1, 2, 3); % returns 2: 3 is at index 2
BinarySearch(A, 1, 2, 1); % returns 1: 1 is at index 1
```

Note that it may not be most efficient to implement this recursively. I'll leave it as an exercise, but this could be easily implemented using a `while` loop instead. The same logical structure would be used.

Answer (score 1):

Try to set breakpoints to examine values where you think a problem might be.

You can use the while loop and the break command to avoid going into infinite loop.

For example try something like this:

```
function [index] = binarySearch(A, n, num)

left = 1;
right = n;
flag = 0;

while left <= right
   mid = ceil((left + right) / 2);

if A(mid) == num
    index = mid;
    flag = 1;
    break;
else if A(mid) > num
    right = mid - 1;
    else
        left = mid + 1;
     end
  end
end

  if flag == 0;
  index = -1;
  end

end
```